# Accessibility: Unordered list not read by voiceover. When targeted by aria-describedby

Tags: ios, html, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When the unordered list is target by aria-describedby it is not read by voiceover. So, How can I make it readable by voiceover.

```
 <div id="body_content">
   <h2 id="heading" aria-describedby="body_content">Heading 1</h2>
   <p>Sample data in the paragraph tag.</p>
   <ul>
     <li>Button 1</li>
     <li>Button 2</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

**Scenerio:** When the focus is moved to heading tag. The screen reader has to read out heading and after that it should read contents targeted using **aria-describedby** automatically. While reading, it should also consider and read **ul li** elements.

If anyone can come up with the solution it would be a great help.

Hi @slugolicious do you have any fix for the requirement??.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it changes something if the H2 is outside body_content ?
I'm wondering if the fact that aria-describedby targets an enclosing element wouldn't have an influence. Logically I think that you shouldn't do so, because you can't be described by a part of yourself.

Comment: @QuentinC, it **is** valid to have an element describe itself by having the label point to the parent element.  The accessible name calculation accounts for this.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2.  Look at 2B, second bullet point, "...and the current node is not already part of an aria-describedby traversal...".  deepak, note that mentioning an "@name" in the body of your question does **not** notify that person that they are mentioned in a question.  In testing this, NVDA on firefox (63) read the <p> and <ul>.  VO on iOS only read the <p>. JAWS on IE didn't read any description.

Comment: Even though this is probably a screen reader bug (not reading all the elements contained in the description), the use of it here is a little weird.  What are you trying to accomplish?  It's hard to think of a workaround when the real purpose is not known.  A heading typically does not need a description, and even if there's an obscure case where it does, why would it need to read paragraphs and lists? A description is supposed to provide further info about an object.  A heading is just a beginning of a section and shouldn't need a description too.

Comment: @slugolicious. Actually when the dialog is opened in a android device with the screen reader talkback. Talkback reads the dialog content automatically. But in **IOS** the focus is moved to the **first element** and reads it out, but it will **not read** the whole dialog contents. So, I am trying to include **aria-describedby** to the focused element, which reads out the referred elements contents, which in turn  helps in reading out the contents of the dialog automatically.

Comment: but now you a presupposing you know how a native voiceover user interacts with their device.  you are trying to force a talkback interaction onto voiceover.  that is generally not a good thing to do.  as long as your dialog is written semantically correct, then how a screen reader interprets it is up to the screen reader.  it won't matter if it's talkback, voiceover, jaws, or nvda.  some good articles on accessible modal dialogs are https://github.com/gdkraus/accessible-modal-dialog and https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2